# Extremely Vague Exception

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I've been working on a project that makes use of wunderground's autocomplete API, and I keep running into a very random error. The code is located [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2966326/autocomplete.zip).

And the exceptions that I'm getting is an AccessViolationException. It occasionally occurs when typing into the textbox.

Exception Information:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(requestURL))
```

> Exception:Thrown: "The specified registry key does not exist." (System.IO.IOException)
>   A System.IO.IOException was thrown: "The specified registry key does not exist."
>   Time: 2013-05-18 14:55:59
>   Thread:Main Thread[5672]
>   Exception:Caught: "The specified registry key does not exist." (System.IO.IOException)
>   A System.IO.IOException was caught: "The specified registry key does not exist."
>   Time: 2013-05-18 14:55:59
>   Thread:Main Thread[5672]

Application.Run(new Form1());

> Exception:Thrown: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." (System.AccessViolationException)
>   A System.AccessViolationException was thrown: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
>   Time: 2013-05-18 14:55:59
>   Thread:Main Thread[5672]
>
> Exception:Thrown: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." (System.AccessViolationException)
>   A System.AccessViolationException was thrown: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."
>   Time: 2013-05-18 15:00:01
>   Thread:Main Thread[4340]

I've tried this on 3 different computers, and after a while .. the same error always happens.

Comment: I have no idea offhand, but it might help if you could track down and post the stack trace from the exception.  That would shed some light on where exactly the error is occurring.

Comment: AccessViolationException is most of the time a bug in an unmanaged component you're using. Somtimes this bug happens because you're doing something the component doesn't like, so there may be a workaround. The best is to contact the component vendor support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro the AccessViolation on Windows 8.  You'd have to enable unmanaged code debugging and enable the symbol server to see the cause, the troublemaker is the AutoComplete message handler built into Windows.  In general a rather cranky piece of code, it is implemented by subclassing the edit control to intercept messages.  The call stack looks like this:

```
shell32.dll!CAutoComplete::_StartCompletion()  + 0x4e bytes 
shell32.dll!CAutoComplete::_OnChar()  + 0x7a bytes  
shell32.dll!CAutoComplete::_EditWndProc()  - 0x6ae52 bytes  
shell32.dll!CAutoComplete::s_EditWndProc()  + 0x23 bytes    
comctl32.dll!_CallNextSubclassProc@20()  + 0x92 bytes   
comctl32.dll!_MasterSubclassProc@16()  + 0xa5 bytes 
user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@36()  + 0xbd bytes  
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()  + 0xf8 bytes 
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()  + 0x10 bytes  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x24d bytes    
// etc.., not interesting
```

This goes wrong because of the TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource property assignment in the TextChanged event handler.  Changing that property has a **lot** of side effects, it forces the edit control window to be recreated so that the new auto-completion list becomes effective.  That interacts very poorly with the subclassing code, probably because it is still using the old edit control whose window was destroyed or runs before Winforms had a chance to re-initialize the new control.

A workaround is to wait setting the property until the event handling is completed.  That can be elegantly done with the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  Change the property assignment to look like this:

```
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        textboxInput.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComplete;
    }));
```

Now the window for the textbox gets destroyed and recreated later, taking the sting out of destroying the window just as it is handling a keydown event.  Do note how the effect of the window getting recreated is readily visible, the textbox flickers like a cheap motel.  I seriously doubt you actually want to use this in a shipping program.

Comment: My compliments for your repro project btw, you made it easy to help you.

Comment: The project was of my own interest. I wanted to learn how to use an external API. I'm guessing that what I wanted to do with the AutoComplete would generally only work with a local SQL database or something like that. Thanks for helping me out!